# Linux won't start on fit-PC3

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I'm at my wits' end with this damned device. I've tried numerous configurations to get Ubuntu to boot on a fit-PC3, from different bootloaders to switching over to UEFI from BIOS booting.

It started out simple. I copied Ubuntu's installation ISO to a USB, plugged it into a USB port on the computer, did some stuff, selected the internal hard disk drive as the target, did some more stuff, turned off the computer, took out the USB drive, and turned it back on. `No bootable medium found.` I repeated this several times with the same results. I was running the computer in BIOS mode.

A little while later, the internal HDD became inoperable for unrelated reasons, so I removed it.

At some point, either immediately before the hard drive failure or after it, I wanted to see if I could get a boot sector program to write text to the screen. If I did this before the hard drive failed, then what I did was copy the first sector of my Ubuntu installer USB to the first sector of the hard drive while booted into the live environment. If this occurred after the hard drive failure, then I erased everything on the installation USB except the first sector. Whatever the case was, the boot sector program printed a message to the screen.

I fiddled around with `grub-mkstandalone` (or it could've been `grub-mkimage`) and I was able to produce a GRUB2 core image that works with BIOS, but trying to boot Linux with it hangs at the single underscore at the top-left corner of the screen. I was also able to produce a core image for UEFI, which was much easier to do. I installed Ubuntu to a USB using a VM and installed my GRUB2 UEFI image to it. In the fit-PC3, GRUB2 gets loaded, but it hangs with the underscore after booting Linux.

The last thing I've discovered is that I am unable to boot the desktop installer in UEFI mode. It hangs the exact same way as before.

I've been saying that I cannot get Linux to boot on the fit-PC3, but that's not completely true. The desktop and minimal installers for Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04 have worked just fine. It isn't obvious to me why those work while my installations don't.

I'd prefer to use UEFI mode for my OS installation.

Comment: [This?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fit-PC). It seems to use AMD64 architecture and doesn't look like there's anything different that would make installing Ubuntu any different than any other device. Can you tell us if and from where you are following a guide to install Ubuntu? Because from what you wrote above it's not clear what you've done or if maybe you are unclear about the installation process: (*"I did some stuff, & some more stuff, I fiddled... etc"*) As far as the reasoning behind the actions you've taken, like what you're doingwith GRUB and UEFI. Where did those ideas come from?

Comment: @Nmath Yes, the third generation of it. I was not following any sort of guide. I "fiddled" with the options that I ran `grub-mkstandalone` or `grub-mkimage` with in terms of what modules it would be preloaded with. I don't know what ideas you are referring to.

Comment: "Ideas" - the deliberately off-the-path way you are going about the system installation.  Per your original question: "*I've been saying that I cannot get Linux to boot on the fit-PC3, but that's not completely true. The desktop and minimal installers for Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04 have worked just fine.*".  You asked how to get Ubuntu to install/boot, and you know how to do this following the tried and true path.  You've given no reason why you need to reinvent the wheel here.  So what exactly is the problem?  What is your actual question?

Comment: @Nmath I don't know what you mean. I tried it the "normal" way using the Ubuntu installer, but that wouldn't boot, so I've been trying to install GRUB manually to find out where it's going wrong. Just now, I used `grub-install` to install GRUB to a USB to boot the fit-PC3 from. Upon selecting the entry from the BIOS, the screen goes black for a second and then returns to the BIOS boot menu.

Comment: I suggest trying to find out why you can't boot into the installation media. Troubleshoot that problem. Ask about that problem. Fix that problem.  Right now, this question seems to indicate that you are stuck with an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) of your own making. I don't think you are going to make any progress down the path you're on.

Comment: @Nmath One, I *can* boot into the installation media, but only in BIOS mode. Two, figuring out why Linux won't boot is *exactly why* I'm doing these things with GRUB.

Comment: ...but it seems that you're trying to skip past the problem instead of going backwards to figure out and fix what"s not working. I'm trying to suggest that won't get anywhere that way.  You either need to figure out why your installation media is invalid, or figure out why your device won't boot in UEFI mode.

Comment: @Nmath I do not get how I am "trying to skip past the problem". The very first step is the bootloader and I'm focusing on that.

Comment: You've gone far off path with whatever you're doing with GRUB.  You've not explained where you got this idea or how you expect it to solve the real problem: that you either don't have valid installation media, or you have a hardware/firmware issue with your boot for which Ubuntu is irrelevant because it's not even loaded yet. Does your installation media pass integrity checks? Did you verify the ISO before flashing? Are you sure you flashed it in a viable manner? If you don't know the answers to these questions, I suggest using BitTorrent for the ISI and Etcher to flash. They'll verify for you

Comment: @Nmath I've written the installation image to USB several times and I get the same result everytime, so I'm pretty sure it was "flashed in a viable member". As far as the "real" problem is, I'm sure that it's the bootloader because I've manually installed it to the target medium more than once for both BIOS+GPT and UEFI mode. Also, I've said that the installation media boots successfully in BIOS mode but in UEFI mode GRUB loads successfully and *then* the screen hangs.